# How to set processing_root in rp5rc

Tags: ruby, processing

I'm attempting to install ruby processing.  I followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/wiki/Getting-Started

After I rake ( before I install jruby ), all of the tests fail.  I get the following result before every print out and not sure how to fix it.

```
WARNING: you need to set PROCESSING_ROOT in ~/.rp5rc
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the tipp by Oscar here is an easy Copy & Paste solution for Mac Users:

```
echo PROCESSING_ROOT: "/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java" > ~/.rp5rc
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the wiki have been updated since you asked this question.

As is now suggested, you can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/monkstone/7438749) to create your `.rp5rc` file. Create a new sketch in Processing using the contents of `SetProcessingRoot.pde` in the gist, and it will suggest the correct PROCESSING_ROOT value for your system and create the file. Note that you'll have to delete the default text ("enter your processing root here") and enter the suggested (or another) path.

Or, if you know the correct PROCESSING_ROOT path for your system, do the following:

`echo PROCESSING_ROOT: \"correct_path\" > ~/.rp5rc`